# Removing space around full stop in qualified name

Tags: spacing

How can I limit the space around a period that are not full stops (i.e., do not end a sentence.)?

In my paper, I need to refer to qualified names (such as `A.x`). Currently, I type-set those as `\texttt{A.x}`. However, this sometimes generates some space around the period, for example in the following snippet:

[image: Qualified name with spacing.]

I'd like to have only a tiny bit of space around the period symbol separating the parts of the name, but everything I could find was related to spacing in math mode. Also, I tried temporarily changing the catcode of `.` to 11, as follows:

```
\newcommand{\codename}[1]{
  \begingroup
  \catcode`.=11
  \texttt{#1}
  \endgroup
}
```

then using `\codename{A.x}`. However, that did not help.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You can use `A{.}x` for that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What exactly is the meaning of `{.}`, and how does it influence spacing? At least I tried, but I'd like to have less space than `A{.}x`.

Comment: The font designer is responsible for the "side bearings" around a glyph.  Wrapping an input character in braces causes it to be set with only the designed side bearings.  So if those are wider than you want or need, a more radical approach will be required.

Comment: It means its content is isolated, and hence has no interaction such as spacing with the glyphs around the content.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it indeed must be 'more radical' :-)

Comment: Have a  try \texttt{A\!.\!x}.

Comment: By the way it's not recommended to mess around with TeX functionalities that you don't fully understand (e.g. catcode in this case), it will *very likely* cause mysterious error messages later.

Comment: Your issue seems to be that, when `\texttt` is used, all characters, including the `.` are of equal width.  That is an inherent characeristic of `\texttt`.

Comment: Without knowing what font you're using for `\texttt` it's really difficult to give advice: the fix is font dependent.

Comment: @Bernard It's quite unlikely that the font has kerning pairs involving the period. So `A.x` and `A{.}x` will produce exactly the same thing.

Comment: @egreg; The font, certainly. But  I guess   the .ldf files  for each language have rules for the spacing  around punctuation in sentences.

Comment: @Bernard With `A.x` no space is added: the bounding boxes for the characters are put next to each other (with possibly, but unlikely in the case of monospaced fonts, automatic kerning between them).

Comment: @egreg: I didn't know that. Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a command:

`\newcommand{\codename}[2]{#1\kern-.05em.\kern-.05em#2}`

Then compare `A.x` with `\codename{A}{x}`:

[image]

Using `\kern` will prevent line breaks and stretching. You can adjust the kern factor however you like. I chose `-.05em` for the length on both sides, but in a different font you might need different lengths before and after.

Comment: Thanks! I indeed needed to adjust the width for my font, but otherwise it is an elegant and simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

I see the main issue of the OP being that he does not like the fact that `\texttt` sets dots in the same width as all other characters.

Here I use a token cycle to address the issue.  I search through every token of the argument to `\codename`.  Every time I find a `.`, I replace it with `\nobreak{\textrm{.}}\nobreak`.  This means that code names with multiple dots are no problem for the macro.

This will avoid spacing introduced by dots as a consequence of context, and by setting the dots in `\textrm`, it will avoid the extra width of the dot, even if the `\codename` is set in `\texttt`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\Characterdirective{\ifx.#1\addcytoks{\nobreak{\textrm{.}}\nobreak}\else
  \addcytoks{#1}\fi}
\newcommand\codename[1]{\tokencyclexpress#1\endtokencyclexpress}
\begin{document}
Here is \codename{A.1} code name.
Code names such as \texttt{\codename{A.2.4}}, can contain multiple dots!
By setting the dots in textrm, extra spacing is avoided even if the 
codename is set in texttt.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is pretty generic and, although I personally went for the other option, I hope it will be helpful to other people.

Comment: @AZWN I'm glad you found something that works for you.  However, I would suggest you compare  the outputs of `\codename{A}{x}
\texttt{\codename{A}{x}}` to see if you are happy with those results from the other answer.